# R:how to extract the first integer or decimal number from a text, and if the first number equal to specific numbers extract the second integer/decimal

Tags: r, integer, decimal, data-extraction

The data is like this:

example - name of database

detail - the first column the contain sting with number in it (the number can be attached to $ etc. like 25m$ and also can be decimal like 1.2m$ or $1.2M)

lets say the datatable look like this:

```
  example$detail<- c("The cole mine market worth every year 100M$ and the equipment they use worth 30$m per capita", "In 2017 the first enterpenur realized there is a potential of 500$M in cole mining", "The cole can make 23b$ per year ans help 1000000 familys living on it")
```

i want to add a column to the example data table - named: "number" that will extract the first number in the string in column "detail". BUT if this number is equal to one of the numbers in vector "year" (its not in the example database - its a seprate list i created) i want it to extract the second number of the string example$detail.

so i create another years list (separate from the database),

```
     years<-c(2016:2030 )
```

im trying to create new column - number

what i did so far:
I managed to add variable that extract the first number of a string, by writing the following command:

```
    example$number<-as.integer( sub("\\D*(\\d+).*", "\\1", example$detail) ) # EXTRACT ONLT INTEGERS

    example$number1<-format(round(as.numeric(str_extract(example$detail, "\\d+\\.*\\d*")), 2), nsmall = 2) #EXTRACT THE NUMBERS AS DECIMALS WITH TWO DIGITS AFTER THE . (ITS ENOUGH FOR ME)

    example$number1<-ifelse(example$number %in% years, TRUE, example$number1 ) #IF THE FIRST NUMBER EXTRACTED ARE IN THE YEARS VECTOR RETURN "TRUE"
```

and then i tried to write a code that extract the second number according to this if and its not working, just return me errors

i tried:

```
   gsub("[^\d]*[\d]+[^\d]+([\d]+)", example$detail)

   str_extract(example$detail, "\d+(?=[A-Z\s.]+$)",[[2]])

   as.integer( sub("\\D*(\\d+).*", "\\1", example$detail) )

   as.numeric(strsplit(example$detail, "\\D+")[1])
```

i didnt understand how i symbolized any number (integer\digits) or how i symbolized THE SECOND number in string.

thanks a lot!!

Comment: Please format the code with indents

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. List item

Since no good example data is provided I'm just going to 'wing-it' here.

Imagine the dataframe `df` has the columns year (int) and details (char), then

```
 df = mutate(clean_details = sub("[^0-9.-]", "",details),
             clean_details_part1 = as.integer(strsplit(clean_details,"[.]")[[1]][1]),
             clean_details_part2 = as.integer(strsplit(clean_details,"[.]")[[1]][2])
      )
```

This works with the code I wrote up. I didn't apply the logic because I see you're proficient enough to do that. I believe a simple ifelse statement would do to create a boolean and then you can filter on that boolean, or a most direct way.

Comment: thanks for your answer!
I tried to apply this on my data but it return me error, I guess its my fault fir not writing a proper example of the data, so i edited it below
thanks a lot

Comment: And im really familiar with all the symbols... i tried to understand all the meaning from Regular expression manual (https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/regex.html) but it wasnt sufficient....
if you have recommendation where to read more about it, it can be really helpfull!
thanks again

Comment: The data you provided is quite convoluted. What if currency amounts don't have currency signs (my script breaks if people use acronyms of millions or billions (m, mm, mil, mill, b, bn, etc.)? What if someone expresses billions in millions (this breaks your check for removing years, e.g., someone may say $2020 million)? 

This is a very nuanced request you're looking for. I think you need to clean the data better first, I recommend looking at NLP packages for cleaning data (text2vec, tidytext, stringr, etc.)  You're looking for someone to clean your data and I don't wanna do that.

Comment: I can handle 5% precent inaccuracy, i know the data is pretty convoluted but the assumptions im making in the "rules" are good enough... (there is no way to clean the data cause its needed a human cleansing and there are thousand of rows... and there will be more and more along the road)
what im trying to figure is the script for extracting the second decimal or integers from a string (if the first one will fall by "accident" cause it was 2020M$ ill live with it)
the things im trying to figure.

and again - thank you for your comments :)